# Update associations in sequelize belongs to many

Tags: javascript, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have a role table and a permissions table. The roles have many permissions and permissions belong to many roles, hence belongs to many association. The association is through 'role_permission', but I haven't explicitly created the model.

**role-model**

```
role.associate = (models) => {
        role.belongsToMany(models.permission, { through: 'role_permission' })
    }
```

**permission-model**

```
permission.associate = (collection) => {
        permission.belongsToMany(collection.role, { through: 'role_permission' })
    }
```

According to docs, I get **setPermissions**,**getPermissions** methods, but I want to update permissions related to a role when I update a role. How can I achieve that. Below is the code for creating a role, but how would a update role (that updates permissions) would look like?

**Code for creating a role**

```
 return collection
            .sequelize
            .transaction((transaction) => {
                return collection
                    .role
                    .create({name, active},{transaction})
                    .then(role => {
                        return role.setPermissions(permissions)
                    },{transaction});
            })
```

Failed code for updating a role

```
collection
    .sequelize
    .transaction((transaction) => {
        return collection
            .role
            .update({
                name,
                active
            }, {
                fields: [
                    'name', 'active'
                ],
                where: {
                    id: data.id
                }
            }, { transaction })
            .then((response) => {
                // ???
                // "role" table is updated
                // but how to update "role_permission" table
            })
    })
```

Comment: For my own understanding...  the `role_permission` table is a junction table.  Unless you are changing the permissions a role has (adding or removing them) I don't think you need to modify that relationship.  Does that make sense?  If you apply the update to the role (name, active, inactive, whatever) it should apply to the relationship because the relationship only has reference to the `id` of the role.

Comment: yes that is right.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change in the `role_permission` table?  Or did you determine that no action is needed?